# How to use pagination in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have fetched hundreds of records from XML to an array variable. When the array is echoed its output is:

```
array(1) {
  [“photo”]=>
  array(2) {
  [”@attributes”]=>
  array(3) {
    [“baseURL”]=>
    string(36) “http://www.myurl.com/photos/event_name11”
    [“thumbDir”]=>
    string(5) “thumb”
    [“largeDir”]=>
    string(6) “images”
  }
  [“pr”]=>
  array(228) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [”@attributes”]=>
      array(5) {
      [“w”]=>
      string(3) “650”
      [“h”]=>
      string(3) “433”
      [“p”]=>
      string(10) “194393.JPG”
      [“n”]=>
      string(6) “194393”
      [“d”]=>
      string(0) “”
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      [”@attributes”]=>
      array(5) {
      [“w”]=>
      string(3) “650”
      [“h”]=>
      string(3) “433”
      [“p”]=>
      string(10) “194394.JPG”
      [“n”]=>
      string(6) “194394”
      [“d”]=>
      string(0) “”
      }
    }
```

I want to display a total of 15 records in a single page, 5 in each row. Images' names and dimensions are in:

```
[“pr”]=>
  array(228) {
```

I have tried using other PHP hard code but could not get desired result. It shows all the records in a single page.

How can I use pagination in CI?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$array = ...
$page = 0; // the page number you want to display
$entriesPerPage = 5;

for($i = 0; $i < $entriesPerPage; $i++)
{
    $entry = $array['pr'][$page * $entriesPerPage + $i];
    // output your $entry somehow
}
```

Or if you want to get 3 rows â 5 infos:

```
$array = ...
$page = 0; // the page number you want to display
$entriesPerRow = 5;
$rowsPerPage = 3;

for($i = 0; $i < $rowsPerPage; $i++)
{
    for($j = 0; $j < $entriesPerRow; $j++)
    {
        $entry = $array['pr'][($page * $rowsPerPage + $i) * $entriesPerRow + $j];
        // output your $entry somehow
    }
    // make a new line
}
```

Comment: Does it work? And if so and you feel well with my answer, Would you be so kind to accept it, please? Thank you in advance.